# Discord.Addons.Interactive.InteractiveBase.PagedReplyAsync Not Working

Tags: c#, discord.net

So I'm testing out the `Discord.Addons.Interactive` namespace to see what it offers. So I write a little `InteractiveBase`  that looks something like this:

```cs
public class Interactive : InteractiveBase
{
    [Command("book")]
    private async Task BookAsync()
    {
        await PagedReplyAsync(new PaginatedMessage
        {
            Title = "Book",
            Color = HelperFunctions.GenColor(),
            Pages = "This is a book".Split(" ")
        });
    }
}
```

So I run the discord bot, everything is well, and then I test out the new book command. Then all of a sudden this happens:

```
Discord.Commands.CommandException: Error occurred executing "book" for USERNAME#XXXX in SERVER/CHANNEL.
 ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Discord.Rest.RestUserMessage> Discord.WebSocket.ISocketMessageChannel.SendMessageAsync(System.String, Boolean, Discord.Embed, Discord.RequestOptions)'.
```

I don't see what I did wrong, but if you do please tell me.

EDIT:
Someone asked for the project file so here it is:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Discord.Addons.Hosting" Version="3.1.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Discord.Addons.Interactive" Version="2.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Discord.Net" Version="2.4.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="5.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="5.0.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Primitives" Version="4.3.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="Images" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Can you provide the project file too please?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/foxbot/Discord.Addons.Interactive/issues/33

There seems to be an issue between `Discord.Addons.Interactive` and `Discord.Net` having the right versions. That's what usually causes `System.MissingMethodException`

Comment: Thank you for this information but what version do I have to update the `Discord.Addons.Interactive` to?

Comment: That package is not longer maintained. You will need to use another interactive lib